# PWM Motor Speed Control

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I recently bought one of [these](http://www.miniinthebox.com/pwm-dc-motor-speed-control-switch-governor-stepless-speed-changing-6v-90v-15a_p481722.html):

When i hooked it up to my 24v power supply and a voltmeter, it was either 0 or 24v with the POT. Nowhere in between. Why is this? Is it becasue this is a PWM device and needs a PWM signal? If so, why did they even include a POT with it...?

Comment: Did you try putting a light load on it - it may not operate as you anticipate without a load

Comment: Whatever else may be going on, a voltmeter (especially a digital one) is not usually able to reliably measure a PWM'd signal - even if at some PWM frequencies you get a proportionate response, at others the reading can be quite wild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put a load on it.
2. From what I can see (given the lack of datasheet), it should generate a PWM w/ the duty cycle proportional to the value of the pot.